# Template Matching using FFT more efficient with gray-scale images?

Tags: image, image-processing, fft, template-matching

Is Template Matching using FFT more efficient if the source and template images are gray-scale images?

Also, let me piggy back. Does any one know of an excellent tutorial to implement Template matching using Fast Fourier Transforms?

Thanks.!

Comment: What do you mean by more efficient? Working in greyscale you have less data to process, but less data for information.

Comment: With Efficient, I mean, would match detection be more accurate if I am inputting both the images as gray-scale images or vice-versa?
Also, would converting input color images to gray-scale images for template matching make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Re excellent tutorial: J.P "Zilla" Lewis's paper on [Fast Normalized Cross-Correlation](http://scribblethink.org/Work/nvisionInterface/nip.html) is hard to beat. Truly a classic.

Comment: I read the paper, Thanks, but implementing the NCC equation without FFT (meaning NCC in spatial domain) doesn't seem to work. Any thing that I would have missed? I know that's a vague question but this might be an easy take for any pros out here.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? Does not work for your imagery? Have you tested your implementation it with a simple pattern, shifting it by a known amount?

Comment: Well it wasn't working because of a silly error. Its working fine in spatial domain. But I am finding it hard to do the correlation in freq. domain with my very limited knowledge. I mean I didn't understand what J.P.Lewis is trying to explain in the above mentioned resource. Any other pointers that I could use?

Comment: J.P. Lewis is saying two things: (1) that computing it in the frequency domain is theoretically more efficient, and practically so when the size of the pattern and search region are more than a few tens of pixels and (2) He is spelling out step by step how to do it. After reading a bit about the property of the Fourier transform, you ought to be able to implement his algorithm in a couple of hours of coding and testing, taking advantage of a library such as fftw (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFTW) to compute the transforms themselves.